# MSVC: static struct std::atomic<bool> Test::g_test has different type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++17

I had the following warning with my Visual Studio 17 (2022) project, and I could reduce it to the following:

#### test1.cpp

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    Test::g_test = true;
}
```

#### test2.cpp

```cpp
#include <atomic>

struct A {
    std::atomic<bool> m_test = false;
};

#include "test.h"

void a() {
    Test::g_test = true;
}
```

#### test.h

```cpp
#pragma once

struct Test {
    static inline std::atomic<bool> g_test = false;
};
```

Result:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>test1.cpp
1>test2.cpp
1>LINK : warning C4744: 'static struct std::atomic<bool> Test::g_test' has different type in 'c:\consoleapplication1\test2.cpp' and 'c:\consoleapplication1\test1.cpp': '__declspec(align(1)) struct (1 bytes)' and 'struct (1 bytes)'
```

Am I violating some C++ rules? Is it an MSVC bug? What would be the best fix/workaround?

Comment: The warning mentions `__declspec(align(1))`. I don't see it in the code you posted. Are you sure the code you posted generates this warning ?

Comment: Pretty sure, yes. As you can also guess from the "ConsoleApplication1" name, that's a new project which I used to try and reproduce. The only non-default setting after creating a new project was to use C++20.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue when using a MSVC version created by cmake using C++17 or C++20... The weird thing is that linker errors are usually prefixed with `LNK`, not with `C`. Are you sure there's only one `test.h`? if both `test?.cpp`s are in different directories `#include "test.h"` could actually refer to 2 different files one of which wouldn't be included in the question.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Here's a video: https://youtu.be/mLMmzSsWmKs Note that it only reproduces in release mode.

Comment: Do you have different settings (specifically, for structure alignment) on the two files (test1.cpp and test2.cpp)?

Comment: As I said above, "that's a new project which I used to try and reproduce. The only non-default setting after creating a new project was to use C++20."

Comment: *"The only non-default setting after creating a new project was to use C++20."* but you tag C++17 :-)

Comment: Unrelated, but `#include <atomic>` should be in test.h to make the header independent.

Comment: @Jarod42 `static inline` variables is a C++17 feature. The bug reproduces with C++17 too, it's just that my project used C++20. And what do you mean "to make the header independent"? In my original project I used precompiled headers.

Comment: By header independent, I meant that every `#include "test.h"` should be preceded by `#include <atomic>` (else you have compiler error), which is sad. So the right place of `#include <atomic>` is not in test1.cpp (test2.cpp still need it as written).

Comment: I am able to reproduce it with Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.11.19). This error will occur even in Debug build, if I change the following `Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties`: first, change `Advanced -> Whole Program Optimization` to `Use Link Time Code Generation`, second, change `C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format` to `Program Database (/Zi)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a compiler bug. See https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3241 and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/10207002.

> Reduced from STL bug report https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3241, this seems to actually be a compiler issue.
>
> Create file  [a.cpp](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=B1506090e504c4b69bf9dbc014c60ceae638044658445102886_a.cpp&tid=1506090e504c4b69bf9dbc014c60ceae638044658445102886):
>
> ```
> template <class T> struct atomic { alignas(sizeof(T)) T x; };
>
> struct S0 { static inline atomic<bool> z; };
>
> int main() { (void) S0::z; }
> ```
>
> and file  [b.cpp](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=Bf046175a4c0947f4bce9a7d16b397387638044659000908350_b.cpp&tid=f046175a4c0947f4bce9a7d16b397387638044659000908350):
>
> ```
> template <class T> struct atomic { alignas(sizeof(T)) T x; };
>
> struct S1 { atomic<bool> y; };
>
> struct S0 { static inline atomic<bool> z; };
>
> void f() { (void) S0::z; }
> ```
>
> then compile with “cl /nologo /std:c++17 /GL a.cpp b.cpp” which emits:
>
> ```
> a.cpp
> b.cpp
> warning C4744: 'static struct atomic<bool> S0::z' has different type in 'b.cpp' and 'a.cpp': '__declspec(align(1)) struct (1 bytes)' and 'struct (1 bytes)'
> Generating code
> Finished generating code
> ```
>
> Notably, no warning is emitted if the declarations of  `S1`  and  `S0`  are reordered in  `b.cpp`.